Could someone suggest a function in R that takes # of sigmas and predicts the proportion of data in normal distribution that falls within this range?
I am not a mathematician but I intuitively understand the normal distribution and its probability function, e.g. I understand that 68.7% of data fall betwwen mu - sigma and mu + sigma.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule
could somebody please point a function in R (or help me write it) that takes in number of sigmas and returns the proportion of data that falls within these many sigmas and vice versa a function that takes the proportion of data and returns the number of sigmas that is necessary to deviate from mean to encompass this data, e.g.
f1(one sigma) = 68.7
f2(68.7) = one sigma
I tried to find it myself for a while but I could not

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

It's just pnorm(n)-pnorm(-n).
